# UIBarButtonItem not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have an asynchronous routine that fetches data from a server. When the refresh button in the navigation  is tapped, I replace it with a `UIActivityIndicatorView`, and that part works fine. The object that fetches the data has a protocol to inform its delegate when it has finished retrieving the data. When the delegate (`UITableViewController` subclass) receives the method, I reload the table view with the new data and assign a new refresh button to the `rightBarButtonItem`. When I do this, however, the `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't change. This happens both when I call the `reloadData` method before the assignment and when I call it after. I don't understand why the change just simply isn't happening. These are the two method calls I'm using.

This works:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
indicatorView.color = [UIColor orangeColor];
[indicatorView startAnimating]; 
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:indicatorView];
```

This is what doesn't work:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshOrderList:)];
```

Am I supposed to change these `barButtonItem`s in a different way?

Comment: Are you sure you're on the main thread?

Comment: The network object calls the delegate method in the completion handler of [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest...]. Is this not on the main thread?

Comment: That's not the way to do it. `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshOrderList:)];`

Comment: Well there we go. I saw the method I've been using on this very site in an accepted answer. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Same goes for the custom view init.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshOrderList:)];
```

You cannot initalise an already initialised object and expect it to work properly. Create a new bar button item and set it as the `rightBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refreshOrderList:)];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you cannot change the values in the bar button item, particularly if it's a system item. If you desire, you can create the two items and have them available in ivars. It's not really that much execution time to create a new one though, especially if it may never be used.

This is being used in the case where on non-UITableViewController UIViewController has an outlet to the UITableView in question.

**Swift 5**

```
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

@IBAction func toggleTableEdit(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
    table.setEditing(!table.isEditing, animated: true)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: (table.isEditing) ? .done : .edit, target: self, action: #selector(toggleTableEdit(sender:)))
}
```